# How to sort same mysql table value using by codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

What I want to do is using codeigniter to select from mysql and sort the value

my database records:

```
Criteria | Question
   A     |    Q1
   B     |    Q2
   c     |    Q3
   A     |    Q4
   A     |    Q5
```

What I want to display in my interface:

```
A
--------
Q1
Q4
Q5

B
--------
Q2

C
--------
Q3
```

this is how my code look like

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('qm_form');
$this->db->join('criteria', 'qm_form.criteria_id = criteria.criteria_id');
$this->db->join('question', 'criteria.criteria_id = question.criteria_id');
$this->db->group_by('criteria_title');
$this->db->order_by('criteria_title','asc','question_title','asc');
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();

MYSQL TABLE
question table
question_id | criteria_id | question_title

criteria_table
criteria_id | criteria_title

qm_form table
qm_id | criteria_id | qm_title
```

any idea how to do it?

thanks

Comment: you could have attempted it yourself first and ask if you encounter any problem, asking without trying and showing your code is no good at all..!

Comment: thanks for Sudhir advice, because my code is very long , I scare I paste the code at here will be more messy

Answer (score 1):

Try with group by like

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('my_table');
$this->db->group_by('Question');
$this->db->order_by('Critera','asc');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

Then print like

```
foreach($result as $element)
{
    $hash = $element['Critera'];
    $unique_array[$hash] = $element
}
```

Comment: Hi gautam3164, thanks for reply, I had try your method, but the problem now is criteria A only show one question which is only show Q1, and the Q4 and Q5 is missing

Comment: Ya, I just update my code in the post, it's still same problem after I group by

Comment: can you print the $result using my ans..??

Comment: hey it is coming yaar...just change 'Question' to `Question`....remove single quotes like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f2f5/5

Comment: ya, but how to I display in html like A = Q1,Q4,Q5 B = Q2 C = Q3

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using two order by commands:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('my_table');
$this->db->order_by("Criteria", "asc");
$this->db->order_by("Question", "asc"); 
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you just need the equivalent of a query

```
SELECT *
  FROM tablename
ORDER BY `Criteria`, `Question`
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d2f07/1)**

I'm not an expert in CodeIgniter but you can try

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tablename');
$this->db->order_by('Criteria ASC, Question ASC');
...
```

**UPDATE:** Based on your comments you need an equivalent of a query

```
SELECT `Criteria`, GROUP_CONCAT(`Question`)
  FROM tablename
GROUP BY `Criteria`
ORDER BY `Criteria`
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d2f07/3)**

Which probably translates to

```
$this->db->select('Criteria, GROUP_CONCAT(Question)');
$this->db->from('tablename');
$this->db->group_by('Criteria');
$this->db->order_by('Criteria', 'asc');
...
```

Assuming that your joins are correct then try

```
$this->db->select('criteria.criteria_title, GROUP_CONCAT(question.question_title)');
$this->db->from('qm_form');
$this->db->join('criteria', 'qm_form.criteria_id = criteria.criteria_id');
$this->db->join('question', 'criteria.criteria_id = question.criteria_id');
$this->db->group_by('criteria.criteria_title');
$this->db->order_by('criteria.criteria_title', 'asc');
```

Comment: Thanks peterm, but what I want is only show one criteria instead of show all criteria, such as A = Q1,Q4,Q5 B = Q2 C = Q3

Comment: @Oscar You do that in your code that builds user interface. You can't get shown output with just `select`. You either need to `group_concat` with `group by` and end up with comma delimited list of questions or you need to fetch result sets for each Criteria separately.

Comment: Thanks peterm, I am newbie on codeigniter, any idea how to do the group_concat in codeigniter ? thanks again

Comment: Thanks, it's almost there, but in qm_form table was join with my question and criteria table, you can view my code in the post, so how to I use the GROUP_CONCAT(Question) in my code? thanks a lot

Comment: @Oscar In order to be able to do that I need to see real field names from both your tables. Because your current code selects `*`. Post your tables structures in your original question.

Comment: @Oscar Actually you missed some fields since in your join you have `'criteria.criteria_id = question.criteria_id'` but anyway assuming that your joins are correct see the updated answer for a probable solution

Comment: thanks, the result become A = Q1 , B = Q2 , C = Q3, the A=Q4,Q5 is missing, any idea how ?